# Suppress close on TForm when hitting "OK" button

Tags: c++, c++builder

How can I suppress to close the form when hitting the OK button? I have the following code:

```
void __fastcall TfrmTillegg_velg::btnOkClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (exp1)
        ShowMessage("Not allowed"); // Don't close form
    else if (exp2)
        ShowMessage("Not allowed"); // Don't close form
    else
    {
        // Do something here
        Close();
    }
}
```

The project is written in Borland c++builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean keeping the dialog created by `ShowMessage` open. then as far as I am aware, you cannot do this. The dialog displayed by `ShowMessage` will close whenever you click any of its buttons. If you want a popup dialog that will not close in this way, you will need to create a custom form yourself and control its behaviour according to your needs.

Just in case your question is referring to your **main** form closing, then you do have an explicit call to `Close()` within your button click event handler above that will cause your form to close whenever both of your `exp1` and `exp2` conditions are false.

```
 else     {         
        // Do something here         
        Close();     // THIS WILL CLOSE YOUR MAIN FORM.
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, bad explanation. I want to keep the main form alive in exp1 and exp2. But I figured it out. The same code worked if I sat the `ModalResult` property of the OK-button to `mrNone`.

Comment: @raze Right now I understand what you mean. I thought you wanted the ShowMessage to stay shown after clicking the OK on that which you cant do.